# why ads disappears in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

I had banner and native test ad inside my app and now it disappears. I am getting this error now.

```
E/ApsLdfGameIdentify(24814): binder error
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
E/Hwaps   (24814): no data in database of APSAPPINFO
I/Ads     (24814): Use 
RequestConfiguration.Builder().
setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("B14F98FEF3A77FA1E6")) 
 to get test ads on this device.
 I/AdCheck (24814): APS: blockAdView!
```

Comment: did you change the device?

Comment: no..............